# Custom links in wordpress menu is active in more than one menu item on loading the site

Tags: wordpress

I have a menu as below

```
<ul>
  <li class="active"><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="index.html#section1">About us</a></li>
  <li><a href="index.html#section2">How it works</a></li>
  <li><a href="index.html#section3">Features</a></li>
  <li><a href="index.html#section4">Pricing</a></li>
  <li><a href="Register now.html">Register now</a></li>
  <li><a href="contact.html">Contact us</a></li>
</ul>
```

Second, third, fourth and fifth `<li>` are different sections in first `<li>` which I made as custom link in wordpress (like http://localhost/adams#section1) and first as a wordpress page. When I added

```
add_action( 'init', 'testimonial_postTypes' );
add_filter('nav_menu_css_class' , 'special_nav_class' , 10 , 2);
function special_nav_class($classes, $item){
 if( in_array('current-menu-item', $classes) ){
         $classes[] = 'active ';
 }
 return $classes;
```

}

in fuctions.php to make the Home page active, all sections are also became active. Where I have to change? I am a beginner in wordpress. Also on scrolling different sections in home page I want to make corresponding menu active.

I am attaching wp admin screenshot here
[link on backend](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2DZB0.png)

Comment: Can you share screenshot of page? where all menu becomes active?

Comment: First five menus are active when loading the website or on click on to any link other than Register Now and Contact Us .

Comment: This has nothing to do with WP. You have to use some js to do this.

Comment: @ Louis XIV How can I write js for wordpress menu?